# Can I give access to all domains in CORS headers DigitalOcean Spaces?

Tags: cors, digital-ocean-spaces

I'm trying to set up CORS. Is it possible to give access to all domains in my space? I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but I don't think so, according to [the documentation](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/spaces/how-to/configure-cors/):

> Origin: Specifies the complete domain of the client you want to access your Space’s resources. The domain should start with a protocol identifier, such as `http`, end with a hostname or hostname and port, and optionally include a wildcard character (`*`) **at the start of the hostname**. For example, `https://*.example.com`. All other settings are only applied to requests from this Origin.

(my emphasis)

In your case, there's no hostname at all; therefore, I'm guessing `https://*` isn't considered a valid value, despite the tickmark in the DigitalOcean Web UI.

However, the wildcard on its own (`*`) is likely to work.